# Incorrect Syntax issue

Tags: batch-file

I'm having a problem with the end of my program listed below 
I entered it in CMD
and it says incorrect syntax how can I fix that

```
:NQ2

cls

echo which has more power

echo 1) C4

echo 2) TNT

set /p logo=

if %logo% == 1 goto correct3

if %logo% == 2 goto incorrect3


:correct3

cls

set /p asd

echo congrats your correct, c4 has about 1.2 more times the power of TNT 

Restart (Y/N)

if %asd% == y goto menu

if %asd% == n goto next question 2
```

Comment: It depends on what you entered in response to the first prompt - but you haven't told us that. If you pressed 'enter' then the `if %logo% == 1 ...` will give you a syntax error because `logo` is *empty* so the command will be resolved as `if == 1 ...` which is a syntax error. If you entered anything except `1` or `2` then the code would proceed to `correct3` since neither of the two preceding commands will take effect. The `restart` command is likely to be in error. You'd need to `echo` it. You're illogically entering `asd` before the `congrats` echo. Again, label `next question 2` is invalid.

Comment: well how would i fix that?

Comment: `if %logo% == 1 goto correct3` should be `if "%logo%" == "1" goto correct3` to fix the first problem. Telling us what you entered would partially solve *our* problem in understanding *your* problem. `goto NQ2` on a line after `if .."2"...` would solve the "if neither 1 nor 2 is entered" problem. You already know how to fix the spaces in labels problem. The `restart` problem is a matter of inserting the `echo` keyword before the `restart`. The illogical placement of the `asd` entry solve by moving the `set/p asd...` to *after* the `echo restart...` And you'd need to do similar things for `asd`

Answer (score 0):

Below are two examples to help you out.

…one using `Set/P`:

```bat
:NQ2
ClS
Echo Which has more power...
Echo 1) C4
Echo 2) TNT
Set/P "logo=[1/2]?"
If "%logo%"=="1" GoTo CA2
If "%logo%"=="2" GoTo IA2
GoTo NQ2

:CA2
ClS
Echo Congrats you're correct; C4 has around 1.2 times the power of TNT.
Set/P "asd=Restart [Y/N]?"
If /I "%asd:~,1%"=="y" GoTo menu
If /I Not "%asd:~,1%"=="n" GoTo CA2
GoTo NQ3

:IA2
ClS
Echo Sorry you're incorrect; TNT has only 83%% of the power of C4.
Set/P "asd=Restart [Y/N]?"
If /I "%asd:~,1%"=="y" GoTo menu
If /I Not "%asd:~,1%"=="n" GoTo IA2

:NQ3
```

…and one using `Choice` *(enter `Choice/?` for command help)*:

```bat
:NQ2
ClS
Echo Which has more power...
Echo 1) C4
Echo 2) TNT
Choice /C 12
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo IA2

:CA2
ClS
Echo Congrats you're correct; C4 has around 1.2 times the power of TNT.
Choice /M "Restart"
If Not ErrorLevel 2 GoTo menu
GoTo NQ3

:IA2
ClS
Echo Sorry you're incorrect; TNT has only 83%% of the power of C4.
Choice /M "Restart "
If Not ErrorLevel 2 GoTo menu

:NQ3
```

Comment: thanks il have to figure this out because i dont understand tat code